# How to user useState hooks on different instances?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am pretty new on JavaScript, React, and hooks and I have created a React useState's hook to increase the counter. Based on the following code, the number changes and it goes up on one record, but when I have more than one record all counters increase no matter which button I click. I would like any suggestion as to why it behaves like this will be greatly appreciated:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import vendors from './vendors.css'

const VendorsShow = (props) => {
  const handleDelete = (vendor) => {
    props.deleteVendor(vendor.id);
  }
  
  const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0)

  // similar to componentDidMount:
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`
  })



  return (
    <div className="vendor-show-div" style={vendors}>
      {props.vendors.map((vendor) =>
        <ul key={vendor.id}>
          <Link to={`/vendors/${vendor.id}`}>{vendor.name}
              - ${vendor.total_cost}
          </Link>
            - <button onClick={() => handleDelete(vendor)}>X</button>
            - <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
        </ul>)}
    </div>
  );

}

export default VendorsShow;
```

Comment: Each element you are mapping would need its own counter state. Either an array of counters, or you abstract a component that maintains its own count state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element you are mapping would need its own counter state. Either an array/object of counters, or you abstract a component that maintains its own count state.

I suggest using an object to store `count` values using the vendor's `id` property.

```
const VendorsShow = (props) => {
  const handleDelete = (vendor) => {
    props.deleteVendor(vendor.id);
  };

  const [counts, setCounts] = useState({}); // <-- initial empty object for counts

  // similar to componentDidMount:
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${Object.values(counts).reduce(
      (total, { count }) => total + count,
      0
    )} times`;
  });

  // initialize/update state when vendors array changes
  useEffect(() => {
    setCounts(
      props.vendors.reduce(
        (counts, { id }) => ({
          ...counts,
          [id]: 0 // <-- store counts by vendor id
        }),
        {}
      )
    );
  }, [props.vendors]);

  const handleCount = (id) => () =>
    setCounts((counts) => ({
      ...counts,
      [id]: counts[id] + 1 // <-- update specific vendor's count
    }));

  return (
    <div className="vendor-show-div" style={vendors}>
      {props.vendors.map((vendor) => (
        <ul key={vendor.id}>
          <Link to={`/vendors/${vendor.id}`}>
            {vendor.name}- ${vendor.total_cost}
          </Link>
          - <button onClick={() => handleDelete(vendor)}>X</button>-{" "}
          <button onClick={handleCount(vendor.id)}>{counts[vendor.id]}</button>
        </ul>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-user-usestate-hooks-on-different-instances]

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `count` is an independent state value not depends on your venders.
You need to include `count` variable for each vender and update them accordingly.
Something like this :

```
const [venders, setVenders] = setState(venders);
<button onClick={() => {
   var temp = [...venders];
   temp [i].count = temp [i].count + 1;
   setVenders(temp);
}>{venders[i].count}</button>
```